# how to increase the font in php designer 8

Tags: editor, phpdesigner

### Increasing font size

---

Dear all,
I have been using notepad++ so far, i am newbie to phpdesigner 8.0
The font size (text) of my editor is so small.
Do any one help me to increase it?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the Way to do it. Try the following steps!

### Steps to edit the textsize in phpdesigner8.0 editor

1. go to : tools > preferences > editor ..you will see loads of options from          here.
2. From there, click editor button within all the options on right side
3. and there you can change size. font family etc.
4. You could also do it with Ctrl + E